# Prove $d(x,y) = 1/m$ is an ultra metric

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be any set, and let $X$ be the set of all functions $\mathbb{N}\to S$.  If $x$ and $y$ are distinct elements of $X$, let $d(x,y) = 1/m$, where $m = \text{min}\{n\in\mathbb{N}: x(n) \neq y(n)\}$.  Define $d(x,x) = 0$.  Prove that $d$ is a metric satisfying 
$$d(x,z)\leq\text{max}\{d(x,y),d(y,z)\}$$ 
$\forall x, y, z \in X$.

I guess the first thing to do would be to show that $d$ satisfies the properties of a metric, i.e.

$\text{(i)}\ d(x,y)\geq 0 \ \text{for all} \  x,y \in X$

$\text{(ii)}\ d(x,y)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x = y$

$\text{(iii)}\ d(x,y) = d(y,x)\ \text{for all} \  x,y \in X$

$\text{(iv)}\ d(x,z)\leq d(x,y)+d(y,z)\  \text{for} \ x,y,z \in X$

The first three are easy, as (i) $1/m$ is always positive as defined, (ii) is part of our definition of $d$, and (iii) the third is obvious from the definition of $m$ since min has no regard to order.  After this, I'm lost.

Comment: Don’t bother with (iv): go directly to the ultrametric inequality, which implies (iv) anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $x=z$, the result is clear, so suppose that $d(x,z)=\frac1n$. If $y=x$ or $y=z$, the result is again clear, so suppose that $d(x,y)=\frac1m$ and $d(y,z)=\frac1\ell$; we need to show that

$$\frac1n\le\max\left\{\frac1m,\frac1\ell\right\}$$

or, equivalently, that $n\ge\min\{m,\ell\}$. If not, then $n<m$ and $n<\ell$. Now consider what this says about $x(n),y(n)$, and $z(n)$.

Comment: It would mean that $x(n)=y(n)=z(n)$, correct?  Then this would contradict that $l,\ m \neq 0$.

Comment: @Claycrusher: It would indeed mean that $x(n)=y(n)=z(n)$, but the contradiction is with the fact that $x(n)\ne z(n)$, since $d(x,z)=\frac1n$.

Comment: Then this would contradict that $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)$ are not $0$.

Comment: Or wait, I guess I wouldn't have to go any further.  We've already concluded that $n\geq\text{min}\{m,l\}$ and can draw a chain of conclusions from there.

Comment: @Claycrusher: You’re working too hard: the contradiction is simply that on the one hand $x(n)=z(n)$, and on the other hand $x(n)\ne z(n)$. Therefore it’s not possible to have $n<\min\{m,\ell\}$, so $n\ge\min\{m,\ell\}$, which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Haha I'm trying to be too rigorous.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: @Claycrusher: You’re welcome!